# Run .exe as plugin or model designer in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I need to create a tool (better as plugin) to run a .exe from a specific folder.

I created the plugin (and I also added a new button as 'click here to run the exe') but it's not clear to me where put the code and which would be that one.

I guess this:

```py
import os
os.system('C:\Python34\my_application.exe)
```

Comment: Unrelated to how to hook up your code to the button, but recommend you use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead of `os.system`.

Comment: Maybe Start here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GccxvQ1ypbc, this is a good starter set of videos on how to build a plugin and qt designer.